# in php after a require or include or require_once / include_once the variables are not visible

Tags: php, php-7

i required a file like this:

```
require('foo.php');
```

in foo.php

```
$a = 'hi there sexy';
```

now in a configuration file from a webshop i use the require.

Afterwards I have
config.php:

```
    require('foo.php');
   return array(
'someconfig' => $a
);
```

I get $a is not defined variable.

When I do

```
    require('foo.php');
    global $a;
```

it works.

I am using php 7

Why?

Comment: The config.php is returning an array; how are you including config.php in your code, and what are you doing with that array?

Comment: Because you forgot to mention that you [did the require inside of a function](http://php.net/language.variables.scope) and [didn't read the manual](http://php.net/include)? The `require`/`include` constructs take scope into account. So where you use them matters, and as always, variable scope matters.

Comment: @Sherif "all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope" i guess that is the part you are referring to?

Comment: No, "_When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs._" would be the part I'm referring to specifically. Your question does not provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because you're stating that the use of `global $a` works, which indicates to me that you did your `require` inside of a function and neglected to mention that.

Comment: actually it is part of a ecommerce shop. The file is called shop.php and does basically this:
`/*mycode example here*/ return array(/*myaccess to vars here*/);`

Comment: @Sherif i still fail to see how it works. `function(){$a= 'bippo'; include 'foo.php';}` does not work. I cannot access `$a` in `foo.php` even though it should clearly have the scope to access `$a`. So the definition does not seem to make sense, it does not inherit the variable scope.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might encounter this in future, Had same problem, found out the issue was I was including files with a function.

Answer (score -4):

You need to call the variable as global if it was defined in another file

you can use that code:
    global $a
    echo $a

Comment: `You need to call the variable as global if it was defined in another file` No you don't

Comment: That's incorrect. PHP has no file scope. The `global` keyword imports variables from the global scope into a function's local scope. i.e. it's use __anywhere__ other than inside of a function is completely meaningless.